# Showing $|\int_{E_n} f|<\epsilon$ for $n \geq N$ where $E_n = \{x \in E: |x| \geq n\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a integrable function on $E$.  Show that for each $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ for which $n \geq N$, then $|\int_{E_n} f|< \epsilon$ where $E_n=\{x \in E : |x| \geq n \}$.

I want to know if this is a proper way to prove this.

First note, by the continuity of measure, $\{E_n\}$ is a descending chain of sets.  I was thinking this follows from the continuity of measure.  But I'm not sure how to show that $|\int_{E_n}f|< \epsilon$.  That is, I'm not sure how to show that I can make the measure over $E_n$ arbitrarily small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the functions $z_n = f \cdot 1_{E_n}$. Then $|z_n| \leq |f|$, and  $z_n(x) \to 0$ for each $x$. The dominated convergence theorem shows $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int |z_n| = 0$, and since $\int z_n = \int_{E_n} f$, the desired result follows (noting that $|\int g| \leq \int |g|$).

Comment: How does this show that $|\int_E f|< \epsilon$?

Comment: I presume you mean $|\int_{E_n} f|<\epsilon$? The above shows that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{E_n}|f| = 0$, and since $|\int_{E_n} f| \leq \int_{E_n}|f|$, you have $\lim_{n\to \infty} |\int_{E_n} f|=0$.

Comment: Do I also need to incorporate anything that deals with continuity of the Lebesgue integral?